# Bad idea to allow user to upload an ini file for parsing?

Tags: php, file, parsing, ini

I am just brainstorming ways to allow a website user to submit information to a site without using web forms. One idea I have seen suggested is to allow a user to upload an ini file containing the information the user wants to submit in ini format. Then use parse_ini_file to get the submitted info into an array which I can then validate and use within the site.

But since ini files are configuration files, this seems a bit scary to allow a user to do. If, as long as all such files are saved outside of the webroot, permissions as read only, with randomized names, and are deleted as soon as they are parsed, is this a bad way from a security stand point to do this?

Again, just brainstorming, would file_get_contents be the better way to go?

Comment: If an .ini file is suitable for your purposes, then it's fine - it's not executable, and it can only affect configuration if it is stored in certain locations.

Comment: I you just want to read/parse data from ini files, you don't have to worry about security issue.

Comment: The site I have in mind will have standard web forms as well to get this same information. The site is for lawyers who can create cases on the site to organize documents for them.  I can see some lawyers finding it easier to just input some info into a file on their computer, upload it to the site, and then see that the new case has been magically generated for them using the info they submitted.

Comment: .ini's are just data. If you are crazy enough to put in support for a directive `format_hard_drive = yes` and actually DO what the .ini directives say, then it's on YOUR head.

Comment: I wouldn't be doing anything with a format_hard_drive key. The information to be passed in would be standardized and the information to be parsed out would be strictly defined. Anything included in the ini file would end up in the array after calling parse_ini_file but if I do not pull out the variable it should do no harm?

Answer (score 1):

Files are files, unless of course you allow a program to actually execute the content (don't do this), the extension is largely unimportant. However, why would you not want forms post? If you're saying you want non-visual post of clumps of data, something like JSON or an XML based solution would be FAR more suitable. Using a ".ini" file upload to submit data is a real fudge and just not what would be considered best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [`parse_ini_string()`](http://php.net/parse_ini_string) instead? This would save you from creating a temporary file and yet provide the same kind of parsing goodness.

As for safety, parsing anything could potentially be an issue, but the most important thing is to sanitize *after* parsing is done.

Answer (score 0):

I trust in YML when it comes to very basic configuration. And i think i would go for a large textarea rather then uploading a file